# Apple Mail.app does not find any emails when searching (though they do show up in spotlight)

Tags: macos, mail.app, mojave, spotlight, search

For a while now, the search function in Mail.app has not been functioning properly. Whenever I search for *anything*, even if I know that such an email exists, nothing comes up. What is odd is that if I search for email in the main Spotlight search bar, I do get search results.

I have tried the following:

- Re-indexing Spotlight
- Removing `Mail & Messages` from the spotlight search settings, and then re-adding it back
- Deleting the entire mail folder in `~/Library` and then re-importing my email, and re-adding my IMAP accounts to force email to re-download from the server
- Removing the envelope index files, to force Apple Mail.app to recreate the index
- Synchronizing my email inboxes
- Rebuilding my email inboxes

None of this has worked... any suggestions? What is quite odd is that when I create a new user account on my Mac, the same issue presents itself. So it doesn't seem to be a problem specific to my user account.

Comment: When you type in the search bar(top right), do suggestions come up, for example email address, subject etc ? Also, are you searching in the right folder? Please add OS version.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii: I'm using macOS 10.14.6. When I type a search in the search bar, suggestions don't come up. I also am definitely searching in the right folder.